# How to nicely init state from database in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I have a Jetpack Compose (desktop) app with a database, and I want to show some UI based on data from the db:

```
val data = remember { mutableStateListOf<Dto>() }

Column {
    data.forEach { /* make UI */ }
}
```

My question is, at which point should I execute my database query to fill the list?

I could do

```
val data = remember { mutableStateListOf<Dto>() }
if (data.isEmpty()) data.addAll(database.queryDtos())
```

The `isEmpty` check is needed to prevent requerying on re-compose, so this is obviously not the way to go.

Another option would be

```
val data = remember { 
    val state = mutableStateListOf<Dto>() 
    state.addAll(database.queryDtos())
    state
}
```

This way I can't reuse a database connection, since it's scoped inside the remember block. And queries should probably happen async, not inside this initializer

So, how to do this nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android the cleanest way is using [view model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth), and call such code in `init`.

In Desktop it depends on the operation. The main benefit of this platform is that there's no such thing as Android configuration change, so `remember`/`LaunchedEffect` are not gonna be re-created.

1. If the initialization code is not heavy, you can run it right inside `remember`.

   ```kotlin
   val data = remember { database.queryDtos() }
   ```

   In case you need to update the list later, add `.toMutableStateList()`
2. If it's something heavy, it's better to go for `LaunchedEffect`. It will have the same lifecycle as `remember` - run the containing code only the first time the view appears:

   ```kotlin
   val data = remember { mutableStateListOf<Dto>() }
   LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
       data.addAll(database.queryDtos())
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Google have a new warning: **Avoid launching asynchronous operations in the `init` block or constructor of a `ViewModel`.**

And advice to define an idempotent initialize() function to explicitly start the state production pipeline.

https://developer.android.google.cn/topic/architecture/ui-layer/state-production#initializing-state-production